# Rails - Heroku/Tumblr DNS Redirect on Different Browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku, dns, cname

I made a Rails application, which I deployed with Heroku. I am using Tumblr as my admin backend. I am trying to point both Heroku and Tumblr to my domain - is this possible? It only works on Chrome right now.

What I have tried:

- pointed www.domain.net CNAME to Heroku domain
- pointed root A to Tumblr IP
- redirected domain.net to www.domain.net

Results:

- Works fine on Chrome! Going to domain.net and www.domain.net both bring me to my deployed web application. Going to domain.tumblr.com also brings me to my deployed web application.
- Does not work on Opera or Firefox - navigating to domain.net brings me to my Tumblr website - that redirect doesn't work. Going to www.domain.net does bring me to my deployed application, though.

Is this the expected result? I'm new to DNS issues.

Thank you so much!

Edit for clarification:
Goal: I want Tumblr to point to my domain, but I also need Heroku to point there. Right now, Opera and Firefox do not redirect from domain.net to www.domain.net; it just brings me to Tumblr. Is there something else I can do to make my redirect work across browsers? Or is this as good as I'm going to get?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do but, DNS records are cached until the TTL or a manual refresh. Also, this may be unrelated but I have seen that https://letsencrypt.org/ (Heroku's uses this free SSL service) has a certificate chain that does not necessarily work out of the box on all platforms.

Comment: Thank you! I added an edit for clarification. The TTL period for the DNS records has passed (everything directs); I'm trying to figure out if there's something I can do to get the redirect to work across all browsers. Gotta love web dev!